# I need to output only the last int that is printed out in this console app. I'm using a foreach loop. C# console app

Tags: c#, foreach

I am trying to Sum the ASCII values for each character in a string. The last number printed out is the only one I want displayed. So if I enter "chris" I get back 99, 203, 317, 422 and 537. 537 is the correct value I want to display, how do I print out 537 only?

```
using System;

namespace BLConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool executeLoop = true;
            while (executeLoop)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a word for the sum of it's ASCII value !!!");
                Console.WriteLine("Type the word 'exit' at any time to escape ...");
                string word = Console.ReadLine();

                if (word != "EXIT" || word != "Exit" || word != "exit")
                {
                    int  sum = 0;
                    foreach (char c in word)
                    {
                        sum += c;
                        Console.WriteLine((int)sum);
                    }
                }

                if (word == "EXIT" || word == "Exit" || word == "exit")
                  {
                    executeLoop = false;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just take the `WriteLine` out of the loop and write the `sum` after the loop is completed.

Comment: move the `Console.WriteLine` statement outside the `foreach` loop

Comment: Also, you can do a case-insensitive comparison like: `if (word.Equals("exit", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))`. And instead of doing the comparison more than once, just use an `else`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply put the `WriteLine` after the loop, so it only writes the final sum. Also, you can just use `true` as the condition for your loop, since `return` will break out of the loop immediately. Additionally, you can use the `string.Equals` method to do a case-insensitive comparison:

```
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a word for the sum of it's ASCII value !!!");
    Console.WriteLine("Type the word 'exit' at any time to escape ...");

    string word = Console.ReadLine();

    if (word.Equals("exit", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        return;
    }

    int sum = 0;

    foreach (char c in word)
    {
        sum += c;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(sum);
}
```